# Getting Random number only once from the range

Tags: ios, random, swift2

I want to return random number from the range of number. The return number will be only once until all the number will be return.

I am using following code to generate random number, but extra i have to do to get number only once?

Function:

```
    func randomNumber(range: Range<Int> = 1...3) -> Int {
     let min = range.startIndex
     let max = range.endIndex
     return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min
    }
```

Calling:

```
    var ran = randomNumber(0...36)
```

Output:

```
ran: 30
ran: 16
ran: 0
ran: 14
ran: 18
ran: 7
ran: 20
ran: 13
ran: 26
ran: 26
ran: 3
ran: 12
ran: 35
ran: 27
ran: 0
ran: 5
ran: 5
ran: 3
```

Please suggest me what changes to be done.

Answer (score 1):

This function creates an array with all of the numbers from 0 to the max (36 in your case). Then it makes a copy of the array and gets a random index from the copied array. When that number is picked, it is removed from the copied array. Repeat as many times as there are numbers in the original array.

```
func random(max: Int) {

    var numbers = [Int]()
    for x in 0...max {
        numbers.append(x)
    }

    var numbersCopy = numbers
    for _ in 0..<numbers.count {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numbersCopy.count)))
        let result = numbersCopy.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)
        print("Random Number: \(result)")
    }
}
```